# Unable to handle http codes in swift iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, http, alamofire

I am new to iOS and swift in my project I am using Alamofire, I am handling successfully data but I am not able to handle differnt kinds  of server codes in simple way can any one help me to solve my problem.

This is my service call

```
func requestPOSTURL(_ strURL : String, params : [String : AnyObject]?, headers : [String : String]?, success:@escaping (JSON) -> Void, failure:@escaping (Error) -> Void){
    Alamofire.request(strURL, method: .post, parameters: params, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: headers).responseJSON { (responseObject) -> Void in
        //print(responseObject)
        if responseObject.result.isSuccess {
            let resJson = JSON(responseObject.result.value!)
            success(resJson)
        }
        if responseObject.result.isFailure {
            let error : Error = responseObject.result.error!
            let dic = ["NSLocalizedDescription" : error.localizedDescription]
            failure(error)
        }
    }
}
```

I am using in my classes like this.

```
AFWrapper.AFsharedInstance.requestPOSTURL(Post_Hod_Indexes_sections_URL, params: dicParams, headers: headers, success: {
    (json) in
    print(json)

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.hideSpinner()

        let swiftyJsonVar = JSON(json)
        let status = swiftyJsonVar["status"].rawString() as!String

        print("status", status)
        if status.isEqual("404") {
            let message = swiftyJsonVar["message"].rawString()
            self.displayMsg(title: "Oops!", msg: message!, style: .alert)
            return
        }
        else if status.isEqual("200") {
            let message = swiftyJsonVar["message"].rawString()
            self.displayMsg(title: "", msg: message!, style: .alert)
            return
        }
        else if status.isEqual("500") {
            let message = swiftyJsonVar["message"].rawString()
            self.displayMsg(title: "", msg: message!, style: .alert)
            return
        } else {
            let message = swiftyJsonVar["message"].rawString()
            self.displayMsg(title: "", msg: message!, style: .alert)
            return

        }
    }

}, failure: {
    (error) in

    self.hideSpinner()
    self.displayMsg(title: "Oops!", msg: "Something went wrong try again after sometime", style: .alert)

})
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get status code from server response using alamofire is `responseObject.response?.statusCode`.(from your code)

```
Alamofire.request(strURL, method: .post, parameters: params, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: headers).responseJSON { (responseObject) -> Void in


    if let code = responseObject.response?.statusCode {
        print(code)

         switch code {

    case 200:
        // OK. you can convert here response in model class, like...

        /*   if responseObject.result.isSuccess {
               let resJson = JSON(responseObject.result.value!)
               success(resJson)
           }
        */
        break
    case 500:
        //Internal server error, do stuff

        break
    case 404:

        //Not fount. Do stuff

        break

     // you can add more case to manage diff. server status code

    default:
        break
    }
   }

}
```

Comment: i am getting multiple http codes , based on code how to show popup.

Comment: for toast you can use third party library, there are many available. Alternatively you can show alert controller.